# How to close C# program, from the second form (not hide) C# Multiform issue

Tags: c#, winforms

Problem: I have created a program that has two forms. When a button is pressed on Form1, the program "hides" Form1 and "shows" Form2. The issue is, when I close Form2, the program continues to run in the background, I believe this is because the program needs Form1 to be closed, not hidden in order for the program to end.

My Question is how do I override the Second Form to close the program and not hide?

```
    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2.Show(); 
        Form1.Hide();
    }
```

I know I could show Form1 again from Form2, and then close, but I would really like to avoid that.

Comment: using `Form1.Close()` instead of `Form1.Hide()` or calling `Application.Exit()` when `Form2` has been closed (I don't know how your application is made, closing `Form1` may even quit application).

Comment: You may like to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/11504844/1588471
Could be the solution to your problem.

Comment: @Adriano That won't work.. When the _"main"_ window is closed the application will terminate.

Comment: @ByteBlast I know, that's why I suggested the other method too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `FormClosed` event:

```
    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2.Show();
        Form2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(form2_FormClosed);
        Form1.Hide();
    }

    void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You have few options to do that, according to how your application is.

First and intuitive solution is to call `Close()` instead of `Hide()` for `Form1`. This works only if `Form1` is not the *main* form of your application (the one inside main message loop started with `Application.Run()`).

Second solution is to add an event handler for the `FormClosed` event of `Form2` and to close first form when second one is closed:

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2.Show();
    Form2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(delegate { Close(); });
    Form1.Hide();
}
```

You can directly close `Form1` or call `Application.Exit()` (in case you did open multiple forms you want to close all together).

Last solution is to make second form the **owner** of first one:

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2.Show();
    Form1.Owner = Form2;
    Form1.Hide();
}
```

This will close automatically the owned form when owner is closed. This is the solution I prefer but it works only for one form (an owner can own only one form).

Comment: Thanks alot, your last solution was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

In application development especially for winforms for the sake of your users, always have a main form (whether an mdiparent or a single parent) that will always be the main form that all other forms show from.

Giving an answer to the question will be encouraging bad programming practice.

Let the mainform close and the application will end. Hiding form1 will not end the application.